# Checkbox outline is larger than checkox in FF on Mac and Safari on IPad

Tags: css, checkbox, cross-browser, outline

My checkbox outline is appearing larger in both width and height on both FF for Mac, and Safari on iPad. It seems to be just fine on everything else.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hazey_coder/VTnc5/4/

I'm using the CSS outline property:

```
input {outline: 1px solid #9D3BC5;}
```

Anyone know of a crossbrowser alternative or anything I can do?

Comment: They look the same to me.  Are you sure this isn't an optical illusion caused by the styling effects of the checkbox itself?

Comment: Are you running FF on OSX? It's not an optical illusion lolz. I think it's the fact that checkboxes are the hardest things to run cross-browser.